# Face Swap Android : How does it work? Blending bitmaps

Tags: android

I am trying to create a face swap application. I was able to go so far as extracting the face and putting it on a base face. The problem I have now is blending the face.

Here is the face I am extracting from :

[image]

and I swap it with this one :

[image]

and I get this :

[image]

How the hell does the Pitu app do it like this :

[image]

Comment: provide some code

Comment: I just draw a bitmap (extracted face) over another bitmap (base). Nothing fancy happening there. I don't think blending the extracted face using any of the PorterDuff Modes will help as the edges / lines will still be visible.